# Using induction with monotonicity to show that $F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) \sqsubseteq F^{n + 1}(\overrightarrow{\emptyset})$

Tags: induction, solution-verification, computer-science, order-theory, monotone-functions

This question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3926697/356308) recent question. The difference is that this question relates to a different proof of a different claim by the authors. Specifically, this question presents an attempted proof of $F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) \sqsubseteq F^{n + 1}(\overrightarrow{\emptyset})$.

I am currently studying the textbook [*Principles of Program Analysis* by Flemming Nielson, Hanne R. Nielson, and Chris Hankin](http://faculty.sist.shanghaitech.edu.cn/faculty/songfu/cav/PPA.pdf). Chapter **1.3 Data Flow Analysis** says the following:

> **The least solution.** The above system of equations defines the twelve sets
> $$\text{RD}_\text{entry}(1), \dots, \text{RD}_{\text{exit}}(6)$$
> in terms of each other. Writing $\overrightarrow{RD}$ for this twelve-tuple of sets we can regard the equation system as defining a function $F$ and demanding that:
> $$\overrightarrow{RD} = F(\overrightarrow{RD})$$
> To be more specific we can write
> $$F(\overrightarrow{RD}) (F_\text{entry}(1)(\overrightarrow{RD}), F_\text{exit}(1)(\overrightarrow{RD}), \dots, F_\text{entry}(6)(\overrightarrow{RD}), F_\text{exit}(6)(\overrightarrow{RD}))$$
> where e.g.:
> $$F_\text{entry}(3)(\dots, \overrightarrow{RD}_\text{exit}(2), \dots, \overrightarrow{RD}_\text{exit}(5), \dots) = \overrightarrow{RD}_\text{exit}(2) \cup \overrightarrow{RD}_\text{exit}(5)$$
> It should be clear that $F$ operates over twelve-tuples of sets of pairs of variables and labels; this can be written as
> $F : (\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star \times \mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star}))}^{12} \to (\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star \times \mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star}))}^{12}$
> where it might be natural to take $\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star} = \mathbf{\text{Var}}$ and $\mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star} = \mathbf{\text{Lab}}$. However, it will simplify the presentation in this chapter to let $\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star}$ be a *finite* subset of $\mathbf{\text{Var}}$ that contains the variables occurring in the program $\mathbf{S_\star}$ of interest and similarly for $\mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star}$. So for the example program we might have $\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star} = \{ x, y, z \}$ and $\mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star} = \{ 1, \dots, 6, ? \}$.
>
> It is immediate that $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star \times \mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star}))}^{12}$ can be partially ordered by setting
> $$\overrightarrow{\text{RD}} \sqsubseteq \overrightarrow{\text{RD}}^\prime \ \ \ \text{iff} \ \ \ \forall i : \text{RD}_i \subseteq \text{RD}_i^\prime$$
> where $\overrightarrow{\text{RD}} = (\text{RD}_1, \dots, \text{RD}_{12})$ and similarly $\overrightarrow{\text{RD}}^\prime = (\text{RD}_1^\prime, \dots, \text{RD}_{12}^\prime)$. This turns $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star \times \mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star}))}^{12}$ into a complete lattice (see Appendix A) with least element
> $$\overrightarrow{\emptyset} = (\emptyset, \dots, \emptyset)$$
> and binary least upper bounds given by:
> $$\overrightarrow{\text{RD}} \sqcup \overrightarrow{\text{RD}}^\prime = (\text{RD}_1 \cup \text{RD}_1^\prime, \dots, \text{RD}_{12} \cup \text{RD}_{12}^\prime)$$
>
> It is easy to show that $F$ is in fact a monotone function (see Appendix A) meaning that:
> $$\overrightarrow{\text{RD}} \sqsubseteq \overrightarrow{\text{RD}}^\prime \ \ \ \text{implies} \ \ \ F(\overrightarrow{\text{RD}}) \sqsubseteq F(\overrightarrow{\text{RD}})^\prime$$
> This involves calculations like
> $$\text{RD}_\text{exit}(2) \subseteq \text{RD}_\text{exit}^\prime(2) \ \ \text{and} \ \ \text{RD}_\text{exit}(5) \subseteq \text{RD}_\text{exit}^\prime(5)$$
> imply
> $$\text{RD}_\text{exit}(2) \cup \text{RD}_\text{exit}(5) \subseteq \text{RD}^\prime_\text{exit}(2) \cup \text{RD}_\text{exit}^\prime(5)$$
> and the details are left to the reader.
> Consider the sequence $(F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}))_n$ and note that $\overrightarrow{\emptyset} \sqsubseteq F(\overrightarrow{\emptyset})$. Since $F$ is monotone, a straightforward mathematical induction (see Appendix B) gives that $F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) \sqsubseteq F^{n + 1}(\overrightarrow{\emptyset})$ for all $n$. All the elements of the sequence will be in $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star \times \mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star}))}^{12}$ and since this is a finite set it cannot be the case that all elements of the sequence are distinct so there must be some $n$ such that:
> $$F^{n+1}(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) = F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset})$$

I have attempted to use mathematical induction to prove this part:

> Consider the sequence $(F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}))_n$ and note that $\overrightarrow{\emptyset} \sqsubseteq F(\overrightarrow{\emptyset})$. Since $F$ is monotone, a straightforward mathematical induction (see Appendix B) gives that $F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) \sqsubseteq F^{n + 1}(\overrightarrow{\emptyset})$ for all $n$.

Appendix A gives the following definition for *monotone function*:

> The function $f$ is *monotone* (or *isotone* or *order-preserving*) if
> $$\forall l, l^\prime \in L_1 : l \sqsubseteq_1 l^\prime \Rightarrow f(l) \sqsubseteq_2 f(l^\prime)$$

I use this definition in the proof below.

For the base case $n = 0$, we get

$$F^0(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) \sqsubseteq F^1(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) \\ \Rightarrow \overrightarrow{\emptyset} \sqsubseteq F(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}),$$

which is true, since the empty set is a subset of all sets.

We want to show that

$$F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) \sqsubseteq F^{n + 1}(\overrightarrow{\emptyset})$$

So we can proceed as follows:

$$F^{n - 1}(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) \sqsubseteq F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) \\ \Rightarrow F(F^{n - 1}(\overrightarrow{\emptyset})) \sqsubseteq F(F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset})) \ \ \ \text{(Since $F$ is monotone.)} \\ \Rightarrow F^{n}(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) \sqsubseteq F^{n + 1}(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) \ \ \ \text{(Since $F^n$ denotes iterated composition, right?)}$$

Is this correct? If not, then what is the correct proof using mathematical induction?

And as an aside, the full formula for the function $F$ is

$$\begin{align*}
\newcommand{\ent}{\mathsf{RD}_{\mathit{entry}}}
\newcommand{\ext}{\mathsf{RD}_{\mathit{exit}}}
\newcommand{\Lab}{\mathbf{Lab}}
\newcommand{\bx}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\by}{\mathbf{y}}
\newcommand{\bz}{\mathbf{z}}
&F(\ent(1),\ldots,\ent(6),\ext(1),\ldots,\ext(6)) =  \\
(&\{(\bx,?),(\by,?),(\bz,?)\}, \ext(1), \ext(2) \cup \ext(5), \ext(3), \ext(4), \ext(3), \\
&(\ent(1) \setminus \{(\by,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(y,1)\}, \\
&(\ent(2) \setminus \{(\bz,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(z,2)\}, \\
&\ent(3), \\
&(\ent(4) \setminus \{(\bz,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(z,4)\}, \\
&(\ent(5) \setminus \{(\by,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(y,5)\}, \\
&(\ent(6) \setminus \{(\by,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(y,6)\}).
\end{align*}$$

Comment: That is correct. The details of $F$ are actually irrelevant here; the monotonicity with respect to the partial order $\sqsubseteq$ is all that you need.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks for the review! Glad to hear that it's correct. If you'd like, you're welcome to post an answer some time, and I'll award you the bounty.