# Using induction with monotonicity to show that $F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) \sqsubseteq \overrightarrow{RD}$

Tags: induction, solution-verification, computer-science, order-theory, monotone-functions

This question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3926616/356308) recent question. The difference is that this question relates to a different proof of a different claim by the authors. Specifically, this question presents an attempted proof of $F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) \sqsubseteq \overrightarrow{RD}$.

I am currently studying the textbook [*Principles of Program Analysis* by Flemming Nielson, Hanne R. Nielson, and Chris Hankin](http://faculty.sist.shanghaitech.edu.cn/faculty/songfu/cav/PPA.pdf). Chapter **1.3 Data Flow Analysis** says the following:

> **The least solution.** The above system of equations defines the twelve sets
> $$\text{RD}_\text{entry}(1), \dots, \text{RD}_{\text{exit}}(6)$$
> in terms of each other. Writing $\overrightarrow{RD}$ for this twelve-tuple of sets we can regard the equation system as defining a function $F$ and demanding that:
> $$\overrightarrow{RD} = F(\overrightarrow{RD})$$
> To be more specific we can write
> $$F(\overrightarrow{RD}) (F_\text{entry}(1)(\overrightarrow{RD}), F_\text{exit}(1)(\overrightarrow{RD}), \dots, F_\text{entry}(6)(\overrightarrow{RD}), F_\text{exit}(6)(\overrightarrow{RD}))$$
> where e.g.:
> $$F_\text{entry}(3)(\dots, \overrightarrow{RD}_\text{exit}(2), \dots, \overrightarrow{RD}_\text{exit}(5), \dots) = \overrightarrow{RD}_\text{exit}(2) \cup \overrightarrow{RD}_\text{exit}(5)$$
> It should be clear that $F$ operates over twelve-tuples of sets of pairs of variables and labels; this can be written as
> $F : (\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star \times \mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star}))}^{12} \to (\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star \times \mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star}))}^{12}$
> where it might be natural to take $\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star} = \mathbf{\text{Var}}$ and $\mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star} = \mathbf{\text{Lab}}$. However, it will simplify the presentation in this chapter to let $\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star}$ be a *finite* subset of $\mathbf{\text{Var}}$ that contains the variables occurring in the program $\mathbf{S_\star}$ of interest and similarly for $\mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star}$. So for the example program we might have $\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star} = \{ x, y, z \}$ and $\mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star} = \{ 1, \dots, 6, ? \}$.
>
> It is immediate that $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star \times \mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star}))}^{12}$ can be partially ordered by setting
> $$\overrightarrow{\text{RD}} \sqsubseteq \overrightarrow{\text{RD}}^\prime \ \ \ \text{iff} \ \ \ \forall i : \text{RD}_i \subseteq \text{RD}_i^\prime$$
> where $\overrightarrow{\text{RD}} = (\text{RD}_1, \dots, \text{RD}_{12})$ and similarly $\overrightarrow{\text{RD}}^\prime = (\text{RD}_1^\prime, \dots, \text{RD}_{12}^\prime)$. This turns $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star \times \mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star}))}^{12}$ into a complete lattice (see Appendix A) with least element
> $$\overrightarrow{\emptyset} = (\emptyset, \dots, \emptyset)$$
> and binary least upper bounds given by:
> $$\overrightarrow{\text{RD}} \sqcup \overrightarrow{\text{RD}}^\prime = (\text{RD}_1 \cup \text{RD}_1^\prime, \dots, \text{RD}_{12} \cup \text{RD}_{12}^\prime)$$
>
> It is easy to show that $F$ is in fact a monotone function (see Appendix A) meaning that:
> $$\overrightarrow{\text{RD}} \sqsubseteq \overrightarrow{\text{RD}}^\prime \ \ \ \text{implies} \ \ \ F(\overrightarrow{\text{RD}}) \sqsubseteq F(\overrightarrow{\text{RD}})^\prime$$
> This involves calculations like
> $$\text{RD}_\text{exit}(2) \subseteq \text{RD}_\text{exit}^\prime(2) \ \ \text{and} \ \ \text{RD}_\text{exit}(5) \subseteq \text{RD}_\text{exit}^\prime(5)$$
> imply
> $$\text{RD}_\text{exit}(2) \cup \text{RD}_\text{exit}(5) \subseteq \text{RD}^\prime_\text{exit}(2) \cup \text{RD}_\text{exit}^\prime(5)$$
> and the details are left to the reader.
> Consider the sequence $(F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}))_n$ and note that $\overrightarrow{\emptyset} \sqsubseteq F(\overrightarrow{\emptyset})$. Since $F$ is monotone, a straightforward mathematical induction (see Appendix B) gives that $F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) \sqsubseteq F^{n + 1}(\overrightarrow{\emptyset})$ for all $n$. All the elements of the sequence will be in $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star \times \mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star}))}^{12}$ and since this is a finite set it cannot be the case that all elements of the sequence are distinct so there must be some $n$ such that:
> $$F^{n+1}(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) = F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset})$$
> But since $F^{n + 1}(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) = F(F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}))$ this just says that $F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset})$ is a *fixed point* of $F$ and hence that $F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset})$ is a solution to the above equation system.
> In fact we have obtained the *least solution* to the equation system. To see this suppose that $\overrightarrow{RD}$ is some other solution, i.e. $\overrightarrow{RD} = F(\overrightarrow{RD})$. Then a straightforward mathematical induction shows that $F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) \sqsubseteq \overrightarrow{RD}$.

I have attempted to use mathematical induction to prove this part:

> In fact we have obtained the *least solution* to the equation system. To see this suppose that $\overrightarrow{RD}$ is some other solution, i.e. $\overrightarrow{RD} = F(\overrightarrow{RD})$. Then a straightforward mathematical induction shows that $F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) \sqsubseteq \overrightarrow{RD}$.

Appendix A gives the following definition for *monotone function*:

> The function $f$ is *monotone* (or *isotone* or *order-preserving*) if
> $$\forall l, l^\prime \in L_1 : l \sqsubseteq_1 l^\prime \Rightarrow f(l) \sqsubseteq_2 f(l^\prime)$$

I use this definition in the proof below.

For the base case $n = 0$, we get

$$F^0(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) \sqsubseteq \overrightarrow{RD} \\ \Rightarrow \overrightarrow{\emptyset} \sqsubseteq \overrightarrow{RD},$$

which is true, since the empty set is a subset of all sets.

We want to show that

$$F^n(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) \sqsubseteq \overrightarrow{RD}$$

So we can proceed as follows:

$$F^{n - 1}(\overrightarrow{\emptyset}) \sqsubseteq \overrightarrow{RD} \\ \Rightarrow F(F^{n - 1}(\overrightarrow{\emptyset})) \sqsubseteq F(\overrightarrow{RD}) \ \ \ \text{(Since $F$ is monotone.)} \\ \Rightarrow F(F^{n - 1}(\overrightarrow{\emptyset})) \sqsubseteq \overrightarrow{RD} \ \ \ \text{(Since $F(\overrightarrow{RD}) = \overrightarrow{RD}$.)} \\ \Rightarrow F^n(\emptyset) \sqsubseteq \overrightarrow{RD} \ \ \ \text{(Since $F^n$ denotes iterated composition, right?)}$$

Is this correct? If not, then what is the correct proof using mathematical induction?

And as an aside, the full formula for the function $F$ is

$$\begin{align*}
\newcommand{\ent}{\mathsf{RD}_{\mathit{entry}}}
\newcommand{\ext}{\mathsf{RD}_{\mathit{exit}}}
\newcommand{\Lab}{\mathbf{Lab}}
\newcommand{\bx}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\by}{\mathbf{y}}
\newcommand{\bz}{\mathbf{z}}
&F(\ent(1),\ldots,\ent(6),\ext(1),\ldots,\ext(6)) =  \\
(&\{(\bx,?),(\by,?),(\bz,?)\}, \ext(1), \ext(2) \cup \ext(5), \ext(3), \ext(4), \ext(3), \\
&(\ent(1) \setminus \{(\by,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(y,1)\}, \\
&(\ent(2) \setminus \{(\bz,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(z,2)\}, \\
&\ent(3), \\
&(\ent(4) \setminus \{(\bz,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(z,4)\}, \\
&(\ent(5) \setminus \{(\by,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(y,5)\}, \\
&(\ent(6) \setminus \{(\by,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(y,6)\}).
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @JohnOmielan They're different proofs of different claims by the authors. But if they're too similar, or posted to close together, then I can delete this one if you'd like?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I only took a quick glance at the earlier one, so I didn't notice that particular difference. I'm sorry for my mistake. As for deleting this question, that is up to you. However, I suggest if you keep this one, then mention in each question text that although they appear similar, they are different proofs of different claims by the authors so other members will not be confused like I was.

Comment: @JohnOmielan That's fine. I added a message at the beginning pointing out that it is similar to the other one. I will edit that message with more information now. I will also edit the other one with a similar message.